# Issues with Cursor when using onmousemove on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I want to create some kind of "drawing" inside an ordinary div (no canvas!). I am using the onmousemove event to trace the position of the mouse. The following code demonstrates my current situation:

CSS Rules:

```
 #outer { width: 400px; border: 1px solid #000000; }
 #inner { width: 100%; height: 20px; background: green; }
```

Actual JavaScript/HTML part:

```
    var is_drawing = false;

    function startdraw() {
        is_drawing = true;

        var div = document.getElementById("inner");
        div.setAttribute("style", "cursor: crosshair");
    }

    function stopdraw() {
        is_drawing = false;

        var div = document.getElementById("inner");
        div.setAttribute("style", "cursor: auto");
    }

    function dodraw(e) {
        if (!e) {
            e = window.event;
        } else if (!is_drawing) {
            return;
        }

        // Some more code to be added later
        var deb = document.getElementById("deb");
        deb.innerHTML = "coords -- x(" + String(e.clientX) + ") y(" + String(e.clientY) + ")";
    }
</script>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner" onmousedown="startdraw()" onmouseup="stopdraw()" onmousemove="dodraw(event)"></div>
</div>
```

**What is expected and the actual result?**

When clicking the inner div and moving the mouse while holding the mouse button, the cursor should be constantly being "crosshair". This also works perfectly with IE9(RC), and partly with Firefox 3.6 - in Firefox, this only works when loading the site and clicking the first time into the inner div. When releasing the button and clicking and moving again, the "not allowed" cursor is shown and the CSS cursor attribute has no effect at all. On Google Chrome the cursor is not even changed (having constantly an input-cursor there).

Which choices I do have? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can help you with is about Chrome: set `onselectstart = "return false"`: http://jsfiddle.net/F2mCS/2/.

Comment: Thanks! This got it working for Chrome. Now, only Firefox is left non-working.

Comment: from @grange, who's not able to comment: When I tried to change the cursor on a canvas element, I needed to return false at the end of the onmousedown handler in addition to add onselectstart as mentioned above. Otherwhise, the cursor still changes to "select" in Chrome.

Comment: @Pontomedon: Chrome has evolved a bit in the meantime. `-webkit-user-select` to the rescue now: http://jsfiddle.net/F2mCS/4/.